# How can I avoid hard-coded queries in my Security config?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-security

I have this piece of code in my Spring Security configuration

```java
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        JdbcUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager = new JdbcUserDetailsManager(dataSource);
        userDetailsManager.setUsersByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, password, enabled FROM users_db.users where username = ?");
        userDetailsManager.setAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, role FROM users_db.user_role WHERE username = ?");

        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsManager);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }
```

It works, but I don't like its hard-coded-ness. That is, the fact that the database name is explicitly specified. If I share the project with somebody else, it wouldn't be enough for them to just adjust `application.properties` to match their database. Not cool

I can remove the database name from queries, but Sage says it's bad practice

> Regarding the database name prefix in the table names, it's generally a **good practice to specify the database name explicitly** in your SQL queries, especially if you're working with multiple databases or schemas. This ensures that the query is executed against the correct database and schema, and reduces the risk of errors due to naming conflicts.

The bot also suggested this as a more flexible alternative

```
# application.properties
user.table=users
```

```java
// the query
// yes, it used an underscore, not a dot
SELECT username, password, enabled FROM :user_table where username = ?
```

```java
String tableName = environment.getProperty("user.table");
String query = "SELECT username, password, enabled FROM " + tableName + " where username = ?";
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
List<User> users = jdbcTemplate.query(query, new Object[]{username}, new UserRowMapper());
```

It looks clumsy which is often a red flag that the AI is headed in the wrong direction. So I decided to ask your advice

**How can (should) I avoid hard-coded queries in my Security config?**

Comment: There are several alternatives to work with typesafe SQL in Java, some examples: https://www.jooq.org/ or http://querydsl.com/

Comment: @doctore do you mean I need external libraries for this?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can use Criteria: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-criteria-queries but for me, that library was never an option when I could decide about it